# Xcode14 crash on launch: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib

Tags: ios, ios16, xcode14

When I upgrade my Xcode to 14, my app crashed and Get an error message:
**dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib**

It's only happen on devices with iOS version below 13，like iOS 12/11，

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely an interoperability issue between Xcode 14 and older iOS version devices. It has been reported multiple times in GitHub issues. Check [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714629) in Apple Developer Forum.

**So for solutions:** add `libSwiftCoreGraphics.tbd` to your project's `Frameworks,Libraries,and Embeded Contents`.

If you are using pods or SPM, also check the updates from the author. For example, `SnapKit` just [upadted](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/pull/763/commits/0159ad71d960499a1a6ba917474b33c5c3cf3a3b) their podfile 5 days ago

[image]

Comment: This solution does not work for me. There's another [ongoing thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714795) on Apple Developer Forums, saying "this is an issue on the Apple side of things."

Answer (score 4):

As per https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714795, Apple suggested adding `-Wl,-weak-lswiftCoreGraphics` to the linker flags.

The problem was that without this flag your app will expect `libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib` to be at `/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib` on the phone. Because the dylib isn't there on older iOS versions, you'll get error like

```
EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
```

Adding the flag tells the linker to treat this library as a weak linker flag. At the launch(or load) time, the dylib will be searched relative to the `@rpath` instead of hard coded `/usr/lib/swift` path.

You can learn more about `rpath` and how that helps `dyld` find the dylibs [here](https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2018/12/05/rpath-what/)

After running `otool -L` on the app I see few more libraries pointing to their `/usr/lib/swift` version but all of them are **weak** references e.g,

```
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreMIDI.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 6.0.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreML.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1436.0.14, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftDataDetection.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 723.0.0, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFileProvider.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 730.0.125, weak)
    /usr/lib/swift/libswiftOSLog.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0, weak)
...
```

The only library with non-weak reference was `libswiftCoreGraphics` before adding the linker flag.

```
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.100.0)
```

After adding the linker flag it appears as:

```
@rpath/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 15.0.0, weak)
```

Comment: It works for me and your explanation makes me clear. Thanks very much.

Comment: @A.K I am not sure, wouldnt it be more wise to add `/usr/lib/swift/` with @executable_path to the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATH to make it search in all possible places? instead of weak linking. What will happen if he try to embed and SDK that depend on this libs the weak link wont help here, no?

Comment: I think `/usr/lib/swift/` is already added and that is why the setup was working for iOS>12. But on iOS-12.1 the library isn't there. Making `libswiftCoreGraphics` relative to @rpath the loader is searching for all places as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

With [Xcode14.1 RC 2](https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/) this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The framework you are trying to compile might be dynamic framework. Try changing your "Embed" content of your framework from **"Do not Embed"** to **"Embed & Sign"** this might fix your crash
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it after updating some pod to Dynamic lyb. Just clean Derived Data, Clean project and run again